# How to fill a 4D matrix with a 2D matrix for every 2D cross section in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

So I have a matrix call it Vjunk which is 70x70x70x70. I have another matrix which is 70x70 call it V.

What I wanna do is that for every i, j the matrix `Vjunk[:,:,i,j]` is 70 by 70. I want to change this matrix so that it is replaced by itself + `V[i,j]` where `V[i,j]` is the ij-th element of my matrix V.

I tried

```
[Vjunk[:,:,i,j]=Vjunk[:,:,i,j]-beta*V[i,j] for i in range(humangrid_size) for j in range(assetgrid_size)]
```

but this command was unsucessful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this indice on Vjunk : (m, n, i, j)

If I'm correct, you want that for every m, n combination, Vjunk(m,n,i,j) get replaced by Vjunk(m,n,i,j) -beta * V[i,j]. If that's the goal, this loop should do the trick :

```
for m in range(70):
    for n in range(70):
        for i in range(70):
            for j in range(70):
                Vjunk[m,n,i,j] = Vjunk[m,n,i,j] - beta * V[i,j]
```

Dunno if it's gonna be fast enough, even if it's only a 70*70*70*70 matrix. Still more than 20M operations.

The loop on i, j could probably get replaced by list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can do it with loops but was just wondering if there is a much faster method that uses vectorization.

Comment: I don't know if there is, just tried it out on my pc with 2 random float matrix. Took less than 30 seconds. Since it's not a matrix too big, loops works fine.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can't put assignments in a list comprehension.

Second of all: you're in luck, because `Vjunk` and `V` readily broadcast when you subtract them. Here is an example with non-trivial shapes to make it easier to spot bugs:

```py
import numpy as np

Vjunk = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4, 5) 
V = np.random.rand(4, 5) 

# naive version: loop
res1 = Vjunk.copy() 
for i in range(2): 
    for j in range(3): 
        for l in range(4): 
            for m in range(5): 
                res1[i,j,l,m] -= V[l,m]

# vectorized, broadcasting version:
res2 = Vjunk - V

print(np.array_equal(res1, res2))
# True
```

Here `Vjunk` has shape `(2, 3, 4, 5)`, and `V` has shape `(4, 5)`. The latter is compatible with shape `(1, 1, 4, 5)` for the purposes for broadcasting, which is then compatible with the shape of `Vjunk`.

Performing the broadcasting subtraction `Vjunk - V` will exactly do what you want: for each element along the last two dimensions each value of `Vjunk` (a 2d array along its first two dimensions) will be decreased by `V`.

It's then trivial to throw in a scalar factor:

```py
res = Vjunk - beta * V
```